# Firestore update is crashing app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let dataRef = database.collection("stores").document(store.id).collection("data").document("storeData")

var storeData: [String:Any] = [:]
storeData["seq"] = store.seq + 1
storeData["shiftSeq"] = store.shiftSeq + 1
dataRef.updateData(storeData)
```

I am receiving the following error when executing the above code. It was working fine until I upgraded to the latest version of Firebase/Firestore

*** Assertion failure in -[FSTWriteStream startWithDelegate:], third_party/firebase/ios/Source/Firestore/Source/Remote/FSTStream.m:244
2017-12-08 10:48:47.819586-0500 centroOne[1833:473631] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Delegate must be nil'

Comment: I hope your pod version is 1.8.4. If it is not, update it then run pod update.

Answer (score 0):

I removed a rule set that was attached to this document and the problem went away. The ruleset referenced a value in another document to make sure it existed.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem in swift recently and solved my problem by checking if documentId exists. In above case, please check store.id exits in your Firestore db and then run update method.